# Override of virtual function ambiguous with diamond inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a diamond inheritance structure like:

```
class Card {
public:
    virtual std::string info() const = 0;
}

class Color : public Card {
public:
    virtual std::string info() const = 0;
}

class Deploy : virtual public Color {
public:
    virtual std::string info() const = 0;
}

class Attack : virtual public Color {
public:
    virtual std::string info() const = 0;
}

class Character : public Attack, public Deploy {
public:
    std::string info() { return "My Info" };
}
```

But in the class Character it says to me:

> override of virtual function "Card::info" is ambiguous

I want to have just one declaration of info in Character. How can I do it?

Comment: I know it's not related to the question and you're still learning, however I would suggest to take a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from missing some `;`s at the end of class definitions and the `return` statement of `Character::info`,
The main issue is that are missing the **`const`** qualifier from the definition of `Character::info`.

I would also add `override` the get help from the compiler if the method does not in fact override a base class method:

```
//-----------------vvvvv-vvvvvvvv----------------------
std::string info() const override { return "My Info"; };
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked, it slipped to me, I didn't see it